# python for loop after update step?

Tags: python, for-loop

I copied this code from [this](http://benalexkeen.com/k-means-clustering-in-python/) website, and am just wondering about the grammar here? Why is the for loop under the 'i+1'?

```
# centroids[i] = [x, y]
centroids = {
    i+1: [np.random.randint(0, 80), np.random.randint(0, 80)]
    for i in range(k)
}
```

The code produce the following results:

```
>>> np.random.seed(200)
>>> k = 3
>>> # centroids[i] = [x, y]
... centroids = {
...     i+1: [np.random.randint(0, 80), np.random.randint(0, 80)]
...     for i in range(k)
... }
>>>     
... 
>>> centroids
{1: [26, 16], 2: [68, 42], 3: [55, 76]}
```

Comment: Irrelevant critique of the code you did not write: would be more efficient to make the `i+1` just `i` and change the range to `range(1, k+1)`.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks! Why is this the case?

Comment: Because the way it is now, an extra addition `i+1` is made in each iteration of the loop where only a single addition operation is needed to adjust the range so that it yields the target keys for the dict.  If only one argument is provided to `range`, the start of the range defaults to `0`.  So essentially, since there is no `start` or `step` argument to `range`, all the `i+1` code is doing is keying each integer in the range to be the next iteration's `i` value (and k in final iteration where `i` is `k - 1`). See [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a dictionary comprehension (similar to a list comprehension), but the brackets make it seem like it's a normal dictionary initialisation.

Imagine if the brackets were on the same line:

```
centroids = {i+1: [np.random.randint(0, 80), np.random.randint(0, 80)] for i in range(k)}
```

So it's just a more verbose way of saying:

```
centroids = {}
for i in range(k):
    centroids[i+1] = [np.random.randint(0, 80), np.random.randint(0, 80)]
```